# Is it possible to tell the compiler that a value referenced by a pointer/reference is not modified over function calls?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
void g();

int f(const int &x) {
  int y = x;
  g();
  return x + y;
}
```

Here, the value in `x` has to be loaded twice before and after `g()` because `g` is allowed to modify the value referenced by `x`.

You can do an explicit load to avoid the problem.

```
int f(const int &rx) {
  int x = rx;
  int y = x;
  g();
  return x + y;
}
```

But C++ has developed in a way that you don't have to write down such details and still have performant code.

Is there a way to tell the compiler in the declaration of `x`, that the value being referenced will not change over external function calls?

Comment: Something like the [`restrict` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) in **C**? Most main-stream C++ compilers have something along the lines of `__restrict`, which does much the same thing.

Comment: GCC at least has an attribute "pure", that tells the compiler that calling g() has no global side-effects. However that is of course not specific to x here. It must not have ANY global side-effects. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#pure).

Comment: Here's `__restrict` in action on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/f8bPYYPET) There are [numerous posts already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+__restrict&searchOn=3) about `__restrict`.

Comment: That's not always feasible solution, but `g` can also be made inline and put into header file.

Comment: Personally, I like the explicit load.  It is robust and makes the intent clear.

Comment: @PaulSanders Is the intent clear without the prose? I would find it extremely confusing.

Comment: @AdrianMole It seems that GCC and Clang has different interpretation of `__restrict` (and even `restrict` when compiling C). GCC still loads twice with `__restrict` in both C and C++.

Comment: @PasserBy Why confusing?  You're telling the reader 'I'm interested in the value of `x` on entry, no matter what'.

Comment: @PaulSanders It would seem redundant especially if `g` is a pure function. The first thing I would suspect is the writer is writing C89 code where declarations must appear before anything else.

Comment: Actually I've seen the opposite in production code. People *rely* on the fact that calling some function changes the input value. Yuck yuck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mark a function as not modifying `x` and from the shown code it is not clear that is even the case. Consider this source:

```
void g();

int f(const int &x) {
  int y = x;
  g();
  return x + y;
}

int t;

void g() { ++t; }

int main() {
    f(t);
}
```

Unless the compiler sees the definition of `g` and can see that `x` can not be modified by it there is no way to avoid the 2 loads. Many compilers won't even try unless `g` is inlined.

Note: gcc/clang have attribute pure to mark functions without side effects:

```
[[gnu::pure]] void g();
```

But a pure function returning `void` means it will never ever get called. Void functions without side effect make no sense.

Comment: From the comments, it seems `__restrict__` can do the job? It has no effect with GCC in this case, but Clang seems to interpret `&__restrict__ x` such that the data referenced by `x` can only be modified by `x` and nothing else.

Comment: @xiver77 That's the problem with compiler extensions, you never know how each compiler implements them. I think clang interprets `__restrict__` to mean that `x` will not be aliased by any other argument.

Comment: Not just any other argument, but any side effect within the scope where `x` is visible. `__restrict__` basically is a feature borrowed from C. It's interesting that the two compilers interpret `restrict` differently also in C (https://godbolt.org/z/xMP4P45x9). Clang omits the second load while GCC doesn't.

Comment: "Void functions with no side effect make no sense" - what about this: `void print_text(const string& message)`? Or is output considered a side effect?

Comment: @Aziuth output is about the biggest side effect there is.

Comment: @xiver77 In C with `restrict` it would be UB for `g` to modify `x` so no second load is ever needed. Looks like a missed optimization.